# Java ArrayList<Class> to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

I have a ArrayList of students, I want to create a json array from this array. I have seen examples done with ArrayList, but those dont work in my case.

**My Student Class has:**

```
String name, lastname;
ArrayList<String> courses;
```

What I tried:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonPlayerArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(students));
    jsonObject.put("jsonPlayerArray",jsonPlayerArray);
    System.out.println("AARRRAAYY: " + jsonPlayerArray.toString());
    System.out.println("JSONOBJEEECCCTTT: " + jsonObject.toString());
```

Results:

```
AARRRAAYY: [[null,null,null,null]]
JSONOBJEEECCCTTT: {"jsonPlayerArray":[[null,null,null,null]]}
```

Idea is to maybe loop though my array and add them individually

> Update with test example

**Call to method**

```
Test test = new Test(); 
test.addData();
```

**Class with function**

```
public class Test {
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> courseSet = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addData(){
        courseSet.add("Java");
        courseSet.add("CSS");
        courseSet.add("Math");
        courseSet.add("Physics");

        students.add(new Student("Jimmy","sad", courseSet));
        students.add(new Student("Kim","don", courseSet));
        students.add(new Student("Barack","Obama", courseSet));
        createJSON();
    }

    public void createJSON(){
        try {
            List<Student> playerList = students;

            JSONObject jsonplayerObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonPlayerArray = new JSONArray(playerList);
            jsonplayerObject.put("jsonPlayerArray", jsonPlayerArray);
            System.out.println("AARRRAAYY: " + jsonplayerObject.toString());


            for (Student s : students) {
                JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(s.getCourses());
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("name", s.getName());
                jsonObject.put("lastName", s.getLastname());
                jsonObject.put("courses", jsArray);
                System.out.println("Json for player class: " + jsonObject.toString());
            }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

**Student Class:**

```
public class Student {

    String name, lastname;
    ArrayList<String> courses;

    public Student(String name, String lastname, ArrayList<String> courses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(ArrayList<String> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
    AARRRAAYY: {"jsonPlayerArray":[null,null,null]}
Json for player class: {"name":"Jimmy","lastName":"sad","courses":["Java","CSS","Math","Physics"]}
Json for player class: {"name":"Kim","lastName":"don","courses":["Java","CSS","Math","Physics"]}
Json for player class: {"name":"Barack","lastName":"Obama","courses":["Java","CSS","Math","Physics"]}
```

Comment: Your `ArrayList` only contains `null` values, of course this is the result you will receive. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: Actually I do have values, And It does work now after I looped though the student array and add them manually (See update). Not sure if the format is correct though. What I mean is this puts each student to JSONObject then on the next loop it overrides the previous Student. Question is if this is the best solution?

Comment: Then you showed us incorrect code to begin with or the wrong result. If `students` doesn't contain 5 `null` values, then the output you presented is not possible. Please edit your question to reflect your actual code.

Comment: My students array contains 4 students, I did show the correct code. Its weird cause when I add them manually by looping It works fine, but when I use `List<Student> studentList = students;
            JSONArray jsonPlayerArray = new JSONArray(studentList);
jsonObject.put("jsonPlayerArray",jsonPlayerArray);` I get null for all 4 of the students

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior at all. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry about that, I have now added my complete code, you can also test it if you think my result isnt right

Comment: Maybe android uses a different version of the library than I do. Thanks for updating your question. I'll defer to those that know Android's libraries better than I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public JsonArray createJsonArrayStudentList(List<Student> list) {
        JsonArray jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for(Student student: list) {
            jsonArray.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("firstname", student.getFirstName())
                .add("lastname", student.getLastName()));
        }
        jsonArray.build();
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, but you dont include arraylist of courses in the student array

Comment: You're using an entirely different JSON library.

Comment: Also, considering the `null` in their JSON, you example would produce `NullPointerException` as soon as you try to dereference `student` in the first iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should try by using Gson
first add it in your dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

and try this

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(courses);
```

Comment: What difference will this make?

Comment: Using String listString = new Gson().toJson(items, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyItem>>() {}.getType()); worked for me